# Superscript in input

Tags: input, vuejs2

I have input number that needs to have .00 superscript like this. I'm using vuejs2 for this. How can I do it? Thanks!

Here's my code

```
<input class="input is-large" type="number" value="0">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-html` to output `<sup>`:

https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/23/

```
<div id="app">
  <input class="input is-large"
  v-model="number">
  <p v-html="supNumber"></p>
</div>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    number: 0
  },
    computed: {
    supNumber: function() {
      return parseFloat(this.number).toFixed(2).split('.').map((e, i) => {
        return (i === 1) ? '<sup>' + e + '</sup>' : new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(e);
      }).join('.');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to input also the .00  is that possible?

Comment: This is what I can think of: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/26/

Just setting `step=0.01` inside `input`. If you mean different font sizes inside input field - I don't know if it's possible.